# missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

My app uses sequelize 6.x with postgresql 14 to select `artwork` with either `forsale` or `fortrade` or both. Both `forsale` and `fortrade` belong to `artwork`. Here is the code:

```
let artworks = await Artwork.findAll({  
            limit:req.query.limit? req.query.limit:1000,//<<==limit:1000
            include:[{
                model:ForSale,
                required: false,
                attributes:["id", "escrow_value", "active_date", "buyer_id", "deposit_date", "close_date", "buy_date","dispute_date", "seller_refund_value", "buyer_refund_value"]
            },{
                model:ForTrade,
                required: false,
                attributes:["id", "escrow_value", "active_date", "bidder_id","poster_refund_value","bidder_refund_value","bid_date","poster_deposit_date","bidder_deposit_date","transaction_closed","close_date"]
            }],
            where: {
                uploader_id:req.viewer.id,  //<<==here req.viewer.id is 1
                status:"active", 
                deleted:false,
                //<<<< either ForSale record exists or ForTrade record exists or both exist.
                [Op.or]: [{
                    '$ForSale.id$': {
                    [Op.ne]: null
                    }
                },{
                    '$ForTrade.id$': {
                    [Op.ne]: null
                    }
                }]
            },
            attributes:{exclude:['fort_token']},
            order:[['id', 'DESC']]
        });
```

Here is the SQL executed and the error:

```
0|server  | Executing (default): SELECT "artwork".*, "forsales"."id" AS "forsales.id", "forsales"."escrow_value" AS "forsales.escrow_value", "forsales"."active_date" AS "forsales.active_date", "forsales"."buyer_id" AS "forsales.buyer_id", "forsales"."deposit_date" AS "forsales.deposit_date", "forsales"."close_date" AS "forsales.close_date", "forsales"."buy_date" AS "forsales.buy_date", "forsales"."dispute_date" AS "forsales.dispute_date", "forsales"."seller_refund_value" AS "forsales.seller_refund_value", "forsales"."buyer_refund_value" AS "forsales.buyer_refund_value", "fortrades"."id" AS "fortrades.id", "fortrades"."escrow_value" AS "fortrades.escrow_value", "fortrades"."active_date" AS "fortrades.active_date", "fortrades"."bidder_id" AS "fortrades.bidder_id", "fortrades"."poster_refund_value" AS "fortrades.poster_refund_value", "fortrades"."bidder_refund_value" AS "fortrades.bidder_refund_value", "fortrades"."bid_date" AS "fortrades.bid_date", "fortrades"."poster_deposit_date" AS "fortrades.poster_deposit_date", "fortrades"."bidder_deposit_date" AS "fortrades.bidder_deposit_date", "fortrades"."transaction_closed" AS "fortrades.transaction_closed", "fortrades"."close_date" AS "fortrades.close_date" FROM (SELECT "artwork"."id", "artwork"."name", "artwork"."author", "artwork"."category_id", "artwork"."wt_g", "artwork"."production_year", "artwork"."dimension", "artwork"."uploader_id", "artwork"."description", "artwork"."note", "artwork"."tag", "artwork"."deleted", "artwork"."status", "artwork"."artwork_data", "artwork"."last_updated_by_id", "artwork"."createdAt", "artwork"."updatedAt" FROM "artworks" AS "artwork" WHERE ("ForSale"."id" IS NOT NULL OR "ForTrade"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "artwork"."uploader_id" = 1 AND "artwork"."status" = 'active' AND "artwork"."deleted" = false ORDER BY "artwork"."id" DESC LIMIT '1000') AS "artwork" LEFT OUTER JOIN "forsales" AS "forsales" ON "artwork"."id" = "forsales"."artwork_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "fortrades" AS "fortrades" ON "artwork"."id" = "fortrades"."artwork_id" ORDER BY "artwork"."id" DESC;
0|server  | Error in myWorkInDeal : Error
0|server  |     at Query.run (/home/node-xyz/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:50:25)
0|server  |     at /home/node-xyz/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:314:28
0|server  |     at async PostgresQueryInterface.select (/home/node-xyz/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:407:12)
0|server  |     at async Function.findAll (/home/node-xyz/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1134:21)
0|server  |     at async /home/node-xyz/routes/artworks.js:562:24 {
0|server  |   name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
0|server  |   parent: error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "ForSale"
0|server  |       at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/node-xyz/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
0|server  |       at Parser.handlePacket (/home/node-xyz/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
0|server  |       at Parser.parse (/home/node-xyz/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
0|server  |       at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/node-xyz/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
0|server  |       at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
0|server  |       at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
0|server  |       at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
0|server  |       at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
0|server  |       at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
0|server  |     length: 120,
0|server  |     severity: 'ERROR',
0|server  |     code: '42P01',
0|server  |     detail: undefined,
0|server  |     hint: undefined,
0|server  |     position: '1615',
0|server  |     internalPosition: undefined,
0|server  |     internalQuery: undefined,
0|server  |     where: undefined,
0|server  |     schema: undefined,
0|server  |     table: undefined,
0|server  |     column: undefined,
0|server  |     dataType: undefined,
0|server  |     constraint: undefined,
0|server  |     file: 'parse_relation.c',
0|server  |     line: '3541',
0|server  |     routine: 'errorMissingRTE',
```

The same error is repeated for table `ForTrade`. The cases in online posts about this error do not fit in this case (caused by UNION). What is missing with the sequelize code?

Here is the model def and association:

```
Artwork.init({
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate:{
             len:{
               args:[1,55],
               msg:"max 55 chars",
             },
           },
    },
    author: {
        type:DataTypes.STRING
    },
    category_id:{  //such as paiting, photo, calligraphy
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER, 
    },
    wt_g: {
      type:DataTypes.DECIMAL(10,2),
    },
    production_year: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    dimension: {
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    uploader_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        notNull:true,
    },
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    },
    note: {
      type:DataTypes.TEXT
    },
    tag: {
        type:DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
    },
    deleted: {
      type:DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue:false,
    },
    status: { 
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      defaultValue:"active"
    },
    artwork_data: {
      type: DataTypes.JSONB
    },
    last_updated_by_id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER},
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE
  }
```

Here is forsale:

```
ForSale.init({
    buyer_id: {
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    artwork_id: {
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false,
    },
    status: {
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    price: {
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false
    },
    shipping_cost: {
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    shipping_method: {
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER, //1-express, 2-air, 3-ground
    },
    transaction_closed:{
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
    seller_refund_value:{type: DataTypes.INTEGER},
    buyer_refund_value:{type: DataTypes.INTEGER},
    escrow_value:{type: DataTypes.INTEGER},
    deposit_date:{type: DataTypes.DATE},
    buy_date:{type: DataTypes.DATE},
    dispute_date:{type: DataTypes.DATE},
    active_date:{type: DataTypes.DATE},
    close_date:{type: DataTypes.DATE},
    seller_receive_payment_date:{type: DataTypes.DATE},
    buyer_receive_product_date:{type: DataTypes.DATE},
    forsale_data: {
        type: DataTypes.JSONB,  //buyer_hashaddress, seller_hashaddress, trade_expense ...
    },
    deployed_address: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    smartcontract_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    last_updated_by_id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER},
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE
 }
```

Here is fotrade:

```
ForTrade.init({
    bidder_id: {
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    artwork_id: {
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false,
    },
    status: {
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    price: {
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false
    },
    shipping_method: {   //1-express, 2-air, 3-ground
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    shipping_cost: {
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    transaction_closed:{
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue:false,
    },
    poster_refund_value:{type: DataTypes.INTEGER},
    bidder_refund_value:{type: DataTypes.INTEGER},
    escrow_value:{type: DataTypes.INTEGER},  //total deposit is 2*escrow_value
    poster_deposit_date:{type: DataTypes.DATE},
    bidder_deposit_date:{type: DataTypes.DATE},
    bid_date:{type: DataTypes.DATE},
    active_date:{type: DataTypes.DATE},
    poster_receive_product_date:{type: DataTypes.DATE},
    poster_ship_product_date:{type: DataTypes.DATE},
    bidder_receive_product_date:{type: DataTypes.DATE},
    bidder_ship_product_date:{type: DataTypes.DATE},
    close_date:{type: DataTypes.DATE},
    fortrade_data: {
        type: DataTypes.JSONB,  //buyer_hashaddress, seller_hashaddress, trade_expense ...
    },
    deployed_address: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    smartcontract_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    last_updated_by_id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER},
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE
 }
```

Here is association:

```
  Artwork.hasMany(ForSale, {foreignKey: 'artwork_id'});
  Artwork.hasMany(ForTrade, {foreignKey: 'artwork_id'});
  ForSale.belongsTo(Artwork, {foreignKey: "artwork_id"});
  ForTrade.belongsTo(Artwork, {foreignKey: "artwork_id"})
```

Comment: The error is related to `'$forsale.id$'` and `$fortrade.is$`

Comment: Try to indicate `subQuery: false` in the main options of the query

Comment: I tried insert subQuery:false after `limit` yesterday and it didn't work.

Comment: Also tried "$artwork.forsales.id$". The error is the same but with `...table artwork->forsales`

Comment: `'Anatoly`, very interesting. it worked today after inserting `subQuery:false` after `limit`. (re-launched app today). What is the purpose of this line? I didn't find a good doc explaining this. Many thanks.

Comment: It means not to join an associated model's table using a subquery (in SQL query) and just join it directly. Look at two generated SQL queries to learn the difference